# Firestore Document values in Android Line Graph

Tags: android, google-cloud-firestore, document, linegraph

I have a collection named PuckData where I store some int values(temperature, light) and timestamp. I would like to display those values in line graphs with Android Graph Library(jjoe64). The first graph will be temperature(yAxis)-timestamp(xAxis) and the second will be light-timestamp. I want the timestamp values to be displayed in this format: dd:mm:yyyy. In the code below I receive the values of temperature and light. I want to get timestamp values also.

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("PuckData").whereEqualTo("region", "Bedroom")
            .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            int light = document.getLong("light").intValue();
                            int temperature = document.getLong("temperature").intValue();
                            Log.d("PUCK", "LIGHT: " + light);

                }
            } else {
                Log.d("PUCK", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

[PuckData Collection Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NJd8V.png)
How is it possible to add them in ArrayLists and pass them as Data points? 
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Please add your database structure.

Comment: I have my PuckData collection and inside it I have documents with the fields: light, temperature(int values), battery(double), region(String), timestamp and the user_id, but I need only to display in graphs the temperature - timestamp and light - timestamp. PuckData is a root folder. Hope this helps

Comment: It doesn't. Please a link to a screenshot.

Comment: I did put a link under my code.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I want to get timestamp values also.

To solve this, please use the following code:

```
Date date = document.getDate("timestamp");
SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
String stringDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
Log.d("DATE", "timestamp: " + stringDate);
```

The output will be the date in `dd/MM/yy` format.

**Edit:**

```
firebaseFirestore.collection("PuckData").whereEqualTo("region", "Bedroom")
            .get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                List<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
                for (DocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                            int light = document.getLong("light").intValue();
                            int temperature = document.getLong("temperature").intValue();
                            Date date = document.getDate("timestamp");
                            SimpleDateFormat simpleDateFormat = new 
                            SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yy");
                            String stringDate = simpleDateFormat.format(date);
                            list.add(stringDate);
                            Log.d("DATE", "timestamp: " + stringDate);
                            Log.d("PUCK", "LIGHT: " + light);

                }
                Log.d("LIST", "list: " + list.toString());
            } else {
                Log.d("PUCK", "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
            }
        }
    });
```

Comment: Could you help me with the graphs? I have already convert the timestamp. I just need the graphs

Comment: Your question was straightforward, you wanted to get the timestamp values which can be done using my code above. If you are asking now, how is it possible to add them in ArrayLists, please see my updated andswer.

Comment: oh sorry I didn't see your code earlier. Could you help me with the graphs as well? how to make the data as x y data points?

Comment: This is basically another question. In order to follow the rules of this comunity, please post another fresh question, so me and other users can help you.

Comment: I have posted a new question but I get no answers.. What should I do? It's urgent.

Comment: You should wait. I'll also take a look.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I'll wait for your help!

Comment: If I'll be able to responde, I'll write you an answer.

Comment: any idea on how I can display the field values as data points in graphs?

Answer (score 0):

In order to get timestamp use:-

```
Date lightTimestamp =  document.getDocument().getDate("light-timestamp");
```

And then you can convert this date to any format you want.

Adding in arraylist:-
You have to create an object with these three attributes. Set data in them and pass them in arraylist.

Comment: Could you please give me sample of code? It's a bit urgent.

Comment: I did. Just need to display them in Android Line Graph now. Thanks!